# How to get/generate pin sha256 from certificate

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Simple question

I am trying to do certificate pinning in android using the network-security-config
but I am not sure how to get the the SHA-256 to put in the pin-set

Given a domain url how do you find the "pin digest="SHA-256"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.com</domain>
        <pin-set expiration="2018-01-01">
            <pin digest="SHA-256">HowDoIGetThisValue</pin>
            <!-- backup pin -->
            <pin digest="SHA-256">HowDoIGetThisValue</pin>
        </pin-set>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Suggestions/Steps.

many thanks

Comment: Hope this thread https://github.com/scottyab/ssl-pin-generator/issues/1 may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in MAC:

if your certificate type is **.crt**:

openssl x509 -in yourCertificatePath.crt -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

if your certificate type is **.cer**:

openssl x509 -in  yourCertificatePath.cer -pubkey -noout -inform der | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

Comment: Hi is yourCertificatePath.crt a root certificate or intermediate

Answer (score 3):

Given the domain URL `example.com`, you can connect to the server and get the certificate pin (as SHA-256) as follows:

```
openssl s_client -servername example.com -connect example.com:443 | \
    openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | \
    openssl rsa -pubin -outform der | \
    openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | \
    openssl enc -base64
```